# System design for a relation that can point to multiple types

Tags: database-design, architecture

My application is basically an accounting balancing program. There are a number of `Ledger` objects that can be cleared by a number of other objects (credit card payments, invoices, bank deposits, etc) that have nothing in common but two fields, `date` and `amount`.

The challenge is how to display information about the actual object that cleared a ledger. In the `Ledger` list view, I'm thinking a html link with basic information, pointing to a view with detailed information about the object.

So when setting and getting the data for the list, how to effectively store and figure out what kind of object cleared the `Ledger`?

I want to emphasize that the objects are fundamentally different except for the two mentioned fields, so there cannot be any inheritance or interface, which won't make any sense in this case since I need to link to the specific object anyway.

**Ideas so far**

1. A field on the `Ledger` for every object that can clear it, and then test which one of those aren't null.
2. An more reflective approach; having a type identifier and the object id stored in the ledger that can be used to return information about it. Perhaps just a factorization of idea #1?
3. Your bright idea here. :)

Comment: Generally, in [double entry bookkeeping](http://accounting-simplified.com/double-entry-accounting.html), you have multiple ledgers, based on account number.  In order to produce all the financial reports people expect, your database mirrors double entry bookkeeping.

Comment: The DSL states that a Ledger is a modification to a bank account. You may regard it as an account transaction if that makes things clearer.

Comment: You can also view the Ledger as one side, and the clearing object as the other side of the double entry bookkeeping. The question is about the system architecture though.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear.  Make your tables look exactly like double entry bookkeeping ledgers.

Comment: That still doesn't solve how to display for example the credit card information connected to a cleared ledger. And I don't see why I should put accounting data on a credit card transaction? It doesn't look, walk or quack like a ledger